# Apply functions to all objects of type "Object"

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype, global

> In **JavaScript**, the properties of `Object.prototype` apply globally (all object types).
>
> For example, I'm making a `keys` function which is applied globally.

```
(Objects)['keys'] = function ()
{
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
};
```

> What would I have to put for `(Objects)` to make the function apply globally but only to `Object` objects and not `Array`, `String`, and `Function` objects?

Comment: `Array.prototype` would replace `(Arrays)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

Comment: @Gavin Thanks, but that's just for arrays. I'm looking to apply other functions I've made to objects or strings.

Comment: For strings https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype

Comment: @Gavin I probably should have asked the question more clearly. I know about `Array.prototype` and `String.prototype` and `Function.prototype` but I was wondering how to apply methods to Objects only. Since Object.prototype actually applies to mroe than just objects, it seems difficult.

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to use `Object.prototype` to apply to just "objects", but you could do some initial checks in the function to deny other types from calling. e.g. `if (typeof this !== "object") { console.error('TypeError: ' + this + '.<your function> is not a function.'); return; }`

Comment: It's not possible, since everything is an object. The only thing you could do is check the type of the value inside the function.